# Is it possible to use SQOOP imported tables without the TRIM function?

Tags: hadoop, hive, trim, azure-hdinsight, sqoop

I have a SQOOP job that loads data directly from an Oracle database to an Hive schema on a Microsoft Azure HDInsights Hadoop Cluster. Although, when importing *char* based fields (such as varchar variables) I found out that these are imported as strings. This has nothing wrong and it works perfect for me. However, there is a small inconvenient, which is the fact that the string field in the Hive Database takes the max length of that field. This will imply the use of the TRIM function every time I perform a condition on that field. Is there any SQOOP parameter or workaround that allow me not to use TRIM?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can import data with varchar datatype as well to avoid get it converted as string. You can use `--map-column-hive` argument to achieve this. This argument overrides the default mapping from SQL type to Hive type for configured columns.

Usage:

```
sqoop import <generic args> --map-column-hive column_name=varchar(200)
```

Comment: I have already looked into that but I need be a little bit more agnostic over specifying the name of the table as I am importing a Database with +- 200 tables. As such I would prefer not to particularly specify any column. In this sense, do you think it can be done?

Comment: Sqoop don't have such functionality except this but through some custom development where you could map the dataype from source to Hive, it can be resolved.